# ¿Cómo puedo modificar una etiqueta html?

Tags: javascript, html

Muy buenas a todos , tengo una duda y no se si esto sea posible . ¿Es posible eliminar la clase y el estilo de esta etiqueta ? He visto algunos vídeos donde con Javascript llegan a cambiar el color de un background pero no se si se puede hacer que con Javascript la pueda eliminar.

Esta es la etiqueta en cuestión :

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="overlow:hidden;display:none;"
```

**Necesitaria eliminar la clase y el estilo**
Muchas gracias a todos por su atención  y por su ayuda

Comment: Claro que se puede, nos compartes que has intentado?

Comment: Pues hasta ahora solo he eliminado esa clase haciéndolo desde el inspeccionar elemento y allí me di cuenta que funcionaba el CSS que quería. ¿Tienes de pronto algun consejo o guia  que pueda seguir para modificar esas etiquetas y otras que tengo? Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si bien todas las respuestas son correctas, te muestro otra alternativa

1.- Accedemos al elemento al que quieres realizarle algo

```
 let element = document.querySelector("ul");
```

2.- Removemos el atributo:

```
element.removeAttribute("style");
```

3.- Removemos la clase, para eso tenemos que acceder a su lista de clases y eliminar la deseada:

```
element.classList.remove("sub-menu");
```

4.- FUENTES:

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

[removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

Comment: Gracias, esto era lo que necesitaba!

Answer (score 1):

Con jquery podrías hacerlo de esta forma

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#boton").on("click",function(){
        $("#parrafo").css("color", "#000000");
    });
});
```

Comment: El OP pregunta sobre JavaScript, tu respuesta es referente a JQuery, lo ideal seria que tambien le expliques que haces en tu codigo, y como podría implementar JQuery a su proyecto,

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. He estado investigando como podria implementarlo y es bastante interesante esta biblioteca

Answer (score 1):

Para remover o ajustar los valores de atributos usando setAttribute()

```js
function update(){
  var element=document.querySelector("ul");
  element.setAttribute("class","");
  element.setAttribute("style","background-color:#ff0");
  console.log(element.outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul class="sub-menu" style="overlow:hidden;display:none;">
 <li>A</li>
 <li>B</li> 
</ul>

<button onclick="update()">update</button>
```

Si deseas eliminarlos por completo el valor y el atributo puedes usar `element.removeAttribute('style');`, por ejemplo.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y por los enlaces!